# How do I write to a unity game's console (after build)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, console

I am making a game server in unity and am running it in `-batchmode`. I have tried `Console.WriteLine` and `Debug.Log` but neither actually print anything to the console (I'm running in a `.bat` file). How should I write to the console? Is there a simple way to do it or how else should I display info about the server running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some searching. It would seem that you can only log to a file if you're using `-batchmode` using the `-logFile` argument and `Debug.Log`.

I did manage to find this custom console example though:
https://garry.tv/unity-batchmode-console if you want to put in the extra effort to be able to write to console.

Similar question here might be useful for you

https://answers.unity.com/questions/884197/redirecting-build-output-to-console-for-automated.html?_ga=2.177817063.358316465.1597205884-742321341.1597081109

Answer (score 4):

Even without explicitly defining a different log location Unity by default always produces the following log outputs (See [Log Files](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html))

> **PackageManager Log**
>
> - Linux
>
>   ```
>   ~/.config/unity3d/upm.log
>   ```
> - macOS
>
>   ```
>   ~/Library/Logs/Unity/upm.log
>   ```
> - Windows
>
>   ```
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\upm.log
>   ```
>
> **Editor Log**
>
> - Linux
>
>   ```
>   ~/.config/unity3d/Editor.log
>   ```
> - macOS
>
>   ```
>   ~/Library/Logs/Unity/Editor.log
>   ```
> - Windows
>
>   ```
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\Editor.log
>   ```
>
> **Player Log**
>
> - Linux
>
>   ```
>   ~/.config/unity3d/CompanyName/ProductName/Player.log
>   ```
> - macOS
>
>   ```
>   ~/Library/Logs/Company Name/Product Name/Player.log
>   ```
> - Windows
>
>   ```
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\CompanyName\ProductName\Player.log
>   ```

So after a build you would be interested in the last one, the player log. Usually it is created the moment you start the app but not filled with content until the app is fully closed.

The exception here is defining the `-logFile -` which directly prints the output to `stdout`/the terminal - see below.

---

If you **want** to redirect the log output to a different file or the command/stdout you can use (see [Command Line Arguments](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html))

> `-logFile <pathname>`
>
> Specify where Unity writes the Editor or Windows/Linux/OSX standalone log file. To output to the console, specify `-` for the path name. On Windows, specify `-` option to make the output go to `stdout`, which is not the console by default.

And use `Debug.Log` as usual.